# How to iterate over a series of directories, running a program and redirecting its output to the input file instead of stdout? (fish)

Tags: fish

Essentially, I want to run a program which takes `FILE` as input over a directory, recursing into each directory and running the program on each file. However, this program outputs a modified version of each file to `STDOUT`, and I want to have it instead output directly to the file it is reading from.

Example

```
foo
--bar.txt
--strob
----strob.cpp
frob.java
```

The program would run on `bar.txt`, `strob.cpp`, and `frob.java`, and write directly to those files instead of `STDOUT`.

A fish solution is preferred, but a bash/POSIX-compatible solution will work as well.

Comment: fish and bash are different languages. Either choose one, or ask separate questions for each. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading-from and writing-to the same file is major hole in Unix/Linux pipelines. When you redirect output to a file with `>`, it first truncates the file to length 0; now reads return EOF. This is a limitation of the kernel API (a race even!) and affects all major shells.

The two workarounds are to either buffer the input in memory, or to redirect the output to a temporary file, and then move it into place. Here is an example in fish of the second case. We'll use `sort` to sort the lines in place. A naive `sort < file.txt > file.txt` will leave the file empty, in all major shells; so we use a temporary file. Example in fish syntax:

```
for file in (path filter -f **)
    set tmp (mktemp)
    sort < $file > $tmp
    mv $tmp $file
end
```

or in one line:

```
for file in (path filter -f **); set tmp (mktemp); sort < $file > $tmp; mv $tmp $file; end
```

To break this down: it first runs `path filter -f **` to find all normal files under this directory. For each such file it creates an empty temporary file, sorts the input into that temp file, and replaces the input with that file.

To generalize this you can create a function which does this temp file dance. Here `inplace` runs a command, saving the output to a temporary file, then outputting that file:

```
function inplace
    set input_file $argv[1]
    set tmp (mktemp)
    $argv[2..] < $input_file > $tmp
    cat $tmp > $input_file
    rm $tmp
end
for file in (path filter -f **); inplace $file sort; end
```

This is not pleasant but I think is the best that can be done given the kernels bestowed upon us.

Comment: Question: why `cat tmp > real; rm tmp` instead of `mv tmp real`?

Comment: @glennjackman overwriting the original file will preserve its attributes, which in a lot of instances can be valuable; replacing the file with a new one will not.